# Upper- and lower control limit do not appear right

Tags: qlikview

Im using the following dataset:

```
LOAD * INLINE [
Year1, MM1
2012, 23
2013, 25
2014, 27
2015, 30
];
```

What I want to is create a control chart like-ish line graph. There I've defined Year1 as Dimension and have created the following expressions:

```
 mean -> Avg({<Year1=>} TOTAL Aggr(Sum({<Year1=>}[MM1]), Year1))
 lower control -> -(2*Stdev({<Year1=>} TOTAL Aggr(Sum({<Year1=>}[MM1]), Year1)))
 upper  control -> +(2*Stdev({<Year1=>} TOTAL Aggr(Sum({<Year1=>}[MM1]), Year1)))
```

The upper- and lower control do not seem to work however (they do appear but not on the right height). Any thoughts on what goes wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add the sigma values to the average to get the control limits.

So LCL:

```
-(2*Stdev({<Year1=>} TOTAL Aggr(Sum({<Year1=>}[MM1]),Year1)))
+Avg({<Year1=>} TOTAL Aggr(Sum({<Year1=>}[MM1]), Year1))**
```

And UCL:

```
(2*Stdev({<Year1=>} TOTAL Aggr(Sum({<Year1=>}[MM1]), Year1)))
+Avg({<Year1=>} TOTAL Aggr(Sum({<Year1=>}[MM1]), Year1))**
```

Then you get this table

[image: Table and Stats]

And you can draw this graph which matches my understanding of the control chart

[image: Control Chart]